# Calculating Distance in R using geosphere

Tags: r, distance, geosphere

```r
library(geosphere)
distm(c(lon1, lat1), c(lon2, lat2), fun = distHaversine)
```

Just wondering that the code above will be calculated based on the shortest distance between these two points instead of the actual distance.

If possible is there any way to actually calculate the distance accurately let's say in the scenario of bike rides from point A to Point B which never the case of a straight line.

Thanks in advance

Comment: (1) use `cbind`, not `c`; (2) I tend to just go with `geosphere::distHaversine(cbind(lon1,lat1), cbind(lon2,lat2))`.

Comment: Its distance calculation will be between `lon1[1],lat[1]` and `lon2[1],lat2[1]`, and the between `lon1[2],lat[2]` and `lon2[2],lat2[2]`, etc. I don't know quite what you mean by "shortest distance" versus actual, are you differentiating between "great circle" versus other? As to your "accurately" comment, you're using Haversine, which has known biases; you might consider `distVincentyEllipsoid` for a more-accurate (though slower) method.

Comment: Thank you so much @r2evans for the tips yes you are correct cbind does the magic as in table I kept getting error of "Error in .pointsToMatrix(x) : Wrong length for a vector, should be 2" when using c ONLY. 

I am pretty new in R and still discovering more (apologies) what I meant by shortest distance using analogy of driving car so distance between 2 points are never straight as I assume is the result of this function. also wondering whether there is a way to calculate that using code in R.

Comment: just to add further clarity for example I am going to a mcDonald near my house using car, the distance calculated using distHarvesine more or less would be calculating straight distance between 2 points (I might be wrong about this). while the actual distance I took could be greater because of using a car. maybe there could be a way linking R with google maps then we could calculate the distance between 2 geo point?

Comment: Okay, so the "shortest distance" is the direct-line approach, whereas the "actual distance" is something Google Maps or similar would direct you to drive? If so, yeah, that's completely outside of the scope of the geospatial package `geosphere`, the package has no concept of roads, or graph-theory traversal with edges and vertices and such. Those types of directions are best left to the truly-hard-math optimization tools out there, such as ... Google Maps. That is not a trivial thing to do, and you need to know a lot about a neighborhood to be able to do that well, fast, and correctly.

Comment: I think you are looking for the `route()` function from the "ggmap" package.

Comment: Hi Evans I think that is pretty clear Thank you for the clarification. Thanks Dave I will lookit up and see how it goes. Appreciate the help from the community

Comment: for extra reference for others maybe this extra reading could help [link](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013-1/kahle-wickham.pdf)